# Application Context Path not working in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

After deploying struts 2 web application on tomcat it failed to map their resources using application context path.

current resources url : http://localhost:8080/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js

and it should be: http://localhost:8080/POS/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js

[Screenshot from my web browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOJwU.png)

But I already set Application context in IntelliJ Idea.
[Screenshot from Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrZqr.png)

Is there anyone to help me to fix this error.

Comment: show us the code how you added path in `<script>` tag

Comment: Thank you @benjamin-c  for support. I just fix my error using add '${pageContext.request.contextPath}'  to src.

Comment: also you can use `jstl` for that

Comment: @benjaminc sure. I'll try that